# Domain of complex function / singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The definition of singularity in Wolfram MathWorld says "Complex singularities are points $z_0$ in the domain of a function $f$ where $f$ fails to be analytic." http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Singularity.html

But in the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, zero is a pole, thus a singularity. So according to the above definition, $z=0$ is in the domain of $f$?

Comment: According to that definition of the domain, yes.  The domain of a complex function is a little complex (har har) to deal with.  Without getting into a whole thing about meromorphic functions, germs of holomorphic sheaves, and so on, it is reasonable to say that a 0 is in the domain of $\frac{1}{z}$ (understood as a meromorphic function).  It would also be reasonable to say that singularities are points in the **closure** of the domain where a function fails to be analytic.

Comment: By the way, a link to the MathWorld definition that you are looking at would be good context to add to your question.

Comment: The MathWorld definition is assuming some standard conventions: a rational function like $1/z$ is considered as defined on the Riemann sphere $\Bbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, with $1/0 = \infty$. It is not analytic at $0$, i.e., it cannot be expressed by a convergent power series in a a neighbourhood of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $z=0$ is not in the domain of $f(z)=1/z$.

$z=0$ is a pole of $f$, and as in the case of every *isolated singularity*, $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $z=0$ minus $\{0\}$.

Comment: I really like this way of looking at things.

Comment: Yiorgos, so you are saying the definition is wrong? that's what I'm asking?

Comment: Yes, the definition is wrong, unless, we consider as range of $f$ the complex sphere $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$.